# how to avoid R automatically converting strings to numbers?

Tags: r, import-from-csv

When I'm reading my data from access or excel, `R` converts the format of variables from "string" to "int".

This is a small sample:

```
NumberFit   stringFit   LetterFit
0           000000000      0
1           000000001      U
2           000000010      L
3           000000011      LU
```

after importing data into `R`, I have:

```
<-States
    NumberFit stringFit LetterFit
          0         0         0
          1         1         U
          2        10         L
          3        11        LU

> str(States)
'data.frame':   514 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ NumberFit: int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ stringFit: int  0 1 10 11 100 101 110 111 1000 1001 ...
 $ LetterFit: Factor w/ 514 levels "0","B","BD","BDL"
```

But, I need the string format of the data. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Assuming you're using `read.csv` or similar, set `colClasses = 'character'`, though you'll have to go do all your conversion manually after the fact

Comment: That's right. Thank you